# Find elements from concatenate strings in JS

Tags: javascript, api

How can I search the values in an Object from strings, something like:

```js
const query = "['arg1']['arg2']"

const renderImage = async (index) => {

    const data = await fetchImage(index)
    const image = document.querySelector('.div')
    
    image.setAttribute("src", data`${query}`)

}
```

The fetch function is perfect working.

Edit:

The image source is in the data['arg1']['arg2']. If I use `image.setAttribute("src", data['arg1']['arg2'])` the code runs fine, but I need to do this dynamically and concatenate strings will help me.

Summing up: can I get the same result data['arg1']['arg2'] concatenating object and "query" (['arg1']['arg2'])?

Comment: Could you please explain a little more about the problem? What is the result and what are you expecting as result?

Comment: I added more informations, but in short, I would get the value insid a object concatenating the object and the "path" to him.

Comment: I think you've used syntax for a tagged template literal ___by accident___ when you wrote `data\`${query}\``.    What did you intend for that to do?  Specifically, what does `data` contain?

Comment: This question is posed as an XY problem.  In particular, you're presuming that the approach of concatenating the parameters `arg1` and `arg2` into a single string `query` is the right thing to do and it almost certainly __is not__.  You should try to leave `arg1` and `arg2` as separate strings, perhaps in an array.  If those two strings must be represented in a single string together, then consider storing them in JSON format as an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can store the path as an array of keys and access it like this

```js
const query = ['arg1', 'arg2']
...
    image.setAttribute("src", query.reduce((o, k)=>o[k], data))
```

Comment: This is a good approach, I would pad out the example a little bit.  Provide an example object like `data = { arg1: { arg2: 42 } }` and show how your `query.reduce` expression will return `42`.  Additionally, you could show how the same code can operate on a jagged array like `data = [[40,41],[42,43]]` with the query `[1, 0]` and would result in `42`.

Comment: @Wyck thanks for the additional details, it is quite clearer like this

Comment: @AhmedLazhar i don't think this is what OP is trying to do. if query was already in an array instead of a string, they would be able to just do `image.setAttribute("src", data[query[0]][query[1]])` their problem is that query is a string.

Comment: I see, but in this case are this query also urlencoded ? I think it is not very clear

Comment: Thank you, the soluction is clean and perfect to me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to extract the property names you want, from a poorly formatted string. Ideally, you would get `query` into a better format to begin with, so you don't have to parse the string. For instance, if you could get query as two separate variables:

```
const query1 = 'arg1';
const query2 = 'arg2';
image.setAttribute("src", data[query1][query2]);
```

you could also store query in a better data type to do this, like `const query = { arg1: 'arg1', arg2: 'arg2' };` then access with dot syntax `data[query.arg1][query.arg2]`.

But if you must keep `query` as this weirdly formatted string for some reason, you can do something like this, parsing the string into it's parts, putting them into an array, then using the array to access the right data within `data`.

```
let query = "['arg1']['arg2']";
query = query.slice( 2 ).slice( 0, -2 ).split( "']['" );
image.setAttribute( "src", data[query[0]][query[1]] );
```

Comment: the JSON.parse solution doesn't work, the query is not JSON encoded

Comment: Thank you, split the args works fine.
My first idea was use a literal strings because actually I have five "args" and only one is dynamic, the other is fixed.

Comment: @AhmedLazhar you're right. not sure what I was thinking. thanks for pointing that out.